# Check Index Pages in Google

Tags: php, curl

I want to check status of multiple sites of Index Pages in Google  for thst i am trying this script but its not giving correct result

```
function getGoogleCount($domain) 
{
  $content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/'.'search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
  $data = json_decode($content);
  $result = intval($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);
  return $result;
}

echo getGoogleCount('printerdriversdownload.com');
```

I am getting result 9750 but if i am checking with site:printerdriversdownload.com in google i am getting 67,300

Please help

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately this appears to be a bug in the API.  you may google "estimatedResultCount bug" or similar to find the slew of folks before you who have posted to the google groups forum looking for an answer/fix for this problem.

The closest I've seen of an answer from google on this issue came from here (the question was very similar to yours): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-ajax-search-api/eQBLXNCt2jw/gm4oZ05e4KIJ

Answer:

> "Unfortunately, the estimated result count is a rough estimate and is
>   not reliable enough to be used for research/exact calculations.  It is
>   subject to frequent change as our index changes.  Also, there are no
>   plans to change its behavior.
>
> Thanks, Ben Lisbakken"

According to his linked in profile Ben Lisbakken was a senior software engineer for google  AJAX APIs from 2009-2011.

Also just a heads up:

on the documentation page for the api you are using it states

> "Note: The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of
>   November 1, 2010. It will continue to work as per our deprecation
>   policy, but the number of requests you may make per day will be
>   limited. Therefore, we encourage you to move to Custom Search, which
>   provides an alternative solution."

which pretty much solidifies that there wont be a fix for your estimatedResultCount issue in the future.

Comment: yaa i notice that before ... but is there any other way to get correct result

Comment: hmm...  You could parse the html from googles actual page to get the count (just keep in mind website layouts are subject to change which could break your code requiring you to update your parser, I'm also not sure if that number can be trusted either).  Or, if you are not set on google, another search engine may have an API which gives more accurate results (bing possibly), but i have not done thorough research on that.